# check weather the sailsjs project is running on live server or on local server

Tags: mysql, node.js, sails.js

i am working on a project in which i am using sailjs in NODE. i've created my DB in config folder by creating a file named "config_db", the code in my config_db is

```
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');

//var sequelize = new Sequelize('databaseNameofLive', 'UserName', 'dbPasswordofLive', {
//    host:"us-cdbr-east-05.cleardb.net",

var sequelize = new Sequelize('DatabaseName', 'UserName', '', {
      host:"localhost",
      dialect: "mysql", // or 'sqlite', 'postgres', 'mariadb'
      port:    3306, // or 5432 (for postgres)
 });

module.exports = {  

    dbase: sequelize

};
```

now each time i need to done a task i pull it on my local PC change DB connection to local and work on it and then change it back to live database and upload again, i need some method through which the app itself check weather it's running on local or live and connect that DB automatically,

like it checks and came to know that this time it's running on local it will connect to following database string

```
  var sequelize = new Sequelize('DatabaseName', 'UserName', '', {
          host:"localhost",
          dialect: "mysql", // or 'sqlite', 'postgres', 'mariadb'
          port:    3306, // or 5432 (for postgres)
     });
```

else it will go to

```
var sequelize = new Sequelize('databaseNameofLive', 'UserName', 'dbPasswordofLive', {
          host:"us-cdbr-east-05.cleardb.net",
```

i'm creating this app using sailsjs in NODE, please let me know how can i do this. and i am using mySQL for my Database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use Node ENV-Variable:

```
if(process.env.NODE_ENV != "production"){
  var sequelize = new Sequelize('DatabaseName', 'UserName', '', {
      host:"localhost",
      dialect: "mysql", // or 'sqlite', 'postgres', 'mariadb'
      port:    3306, // or 5432 (for postgres)
 });
}else{
   var sequelize = new Sequelize('databaseNameofLive', 'UserName', 'dbPasswordofLive', {
      host:"us-cdbr-east-05.cleardb.net",....
}
```

Just make sure, yout set the NODE_ENV right at your live-server!

Btw. why you use Squelinze? Sails come with Waterline (also a ORM).